# Nested Multiple Guards (Protected Routes) in react-router-dom v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a scenario like, 3 pages **Login**, **ResetPassword**, **Home** and condition are:

1. Login can be accessed by anyone.
2. ResetPassword can be accessed by the people who get `{status:"pass_expire"}` in response of Login API hit. This page can also be accessed by people who have successfully logged in and now they want to change password.
3. Home can be accessed by people who have got `{status:"success"}` in the response of Login API hit.

I have thought of doing 2 guards where, **Login** would be outside both Guard,  **ResetPassword** would be inside 1st guard and outside 2nd guard, Home would be inside 1st and 2nd guard.

My main routing file has:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Link to="/resetPass">Reset Password</Link>
    <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
  </div>
  <div>
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path="/login"
        element={
          status ? (
            status !== "pass_expire" ? (
              <Navigate to="/home" />
            ) : (
              <Navigate to="/resetPass" />
            )
          ) : (
            <Login />
          )
        }
      />

      <Route path="" element={<Guard1 />}>
        <Route path="resetPass" element={<ResetPassword />} />
        <Route path="" element={<Guard2 />}>
          <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>

      <Route
        path="*"
        element={
          !status ? (
            <Navigate to="/login" />
          ) : status === "pass_expire" ? (
            <Navigate to="/resetPass" />
          ) : (
            <Navigate to="/home" />
          )
        }
      />
    </Routes>
  </div>
</Router>
```

My Guard1.js File has

```
const Guard1 = () => {
  const { status } = responseData(); // getting all the data from login API response

  if (!status) {
    return <Navigate to="login" />;
  }
  return <Outlet />;
};
```

My Guard2.js file has

```
const Guard2 = () => {
  const { status } = responseData();

  if (status && status !== "pass_expire") {
    return <Outlet />;
  }
}
```

Everything is working fine in `{status:"success"}` but when I am getting `{status:"pass_expire"}` , I can navigate to "/home" route which is not correct.

Comment: Do you basically have just the "three" statuses, `"pass_expire"`, `"success"`, and undefined? And basically as long as the status is defined users can access protected routes except `"/home"` which needs to not be expired? Or is it safe to say that only the non-`"pass_expire"` routes are protected and all others should redirect to log user in? What does `responseData` do? Is it an asynchronous call? Can you include that code in your post?

Comment: I am getting the status perfectly in all the components. I have only 2 response of status "pass_expire" and "success" and anybody could access the login page. My main app pages will be in the same level as /home page

Comment: So what do you want to happen when the path is `"/home"` and `status` is equal to `"pass_expire"`? Currently `Guard2` returns undefined. Do you want to redirect elsewhere?

Comment: when status="pass_expire" and user tries to go to "/home" it should redirect to "/resetPass"

Comment: In the answer I provided I redirected to `"/login"` which has a guard that redirects again to `"/resetpass"`. The net result is the same. You could easily redirect to `"/resetpass"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the part that is missing with your code is the `Guard2` component doesn't redirect off the `"/home"` path when the `status` is `"pass_expire"`.

I suggest this refactor:

Create route guards:

Allows access to routes when "unauthenticated", otherwise redirects to "authenticated" routes.

```
const AnonymousGuard = () => {
  const { status } = responseData();

  return status ? (
    <Navigate to={status !== "pass_expire" ? "/home" : "/resetPass"} replace />
  ) : (
    <Outlet />
  );
};
```

If "unauthenticated" redirect, otherwise render routed content.

```
const Guard1 = () => {
  const { status } = responseData();

  if (!status) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }
  return <Outlet />;
};
```

The `Guard2` is a more restrictive "authentication" guard, the status can't be expired.

```
const Guard2 = () => {
  const { status } = responseData();

  return !status || status !== "pass_expire" ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" replace />
  );
};
```

Usage:

```
<div>
  <Link to="/resetPass">Reset Password</Link>
  <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
  <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
</div>
<div>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<AnonymousGuard />}>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Route>

    <Route element={<Guard1 />}>
      <Route path="/resetPass" element={<ResetPassword />} />
      <Route element={<Guard2 />}>
        <Route path="/home" element={<Home />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>

    <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/home" replace />} />
  </Routes>
</div>
```

[image: Edit nested-multiple-guards-protected-routes-in-react-router-dom-v6]